# grammar - No + singular/plural noun + singular/plural verb

Tags: grammar

Which of the following phrases is grammatically correct?

no animal is

no animal are

no animals is

no animals are

Thanks.

Comment: Suggested migrating this Q to ell.se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second and third are NEVER used. Whether you use 'no animal is', or 'no animals are' depends on whether you are talking in the singular or plural.

You could say '*No animal is* as large as an elephant', but '*no animals are* larger than elephants'.

Comment: What is wrong with the third one? "No" is used to indicate that zero of the noun is the subject, so shouldn't it come with singular verb?

Comment: But the subject, in that case, is still plural. 'No' is simply used here as an adjective qualifying 'animals'. In 'large animals eat lots of food', the verb 'eat' is used in the plural form. Equally 'No animals eat more than lions'but 'no animal eats more than the lion'.